# How to add more than two BigDecimals fields to calculate the sum in a By Collector grouping

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, bigdecimal

This is my method where I group the values ​​and perform a sum of all the outstanding balances of the client.

But I have two more values, which I need to calculate the sum:
 `BigDecimal saldoPendienteMoroso;  BigDecimal saldoPendienteNoMoroso;`

My problem is that, not if it can be sent in the same `groupingBy`:

````
        return data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new TupleCliente(p.getNumeroDocumentoIdentidadCliente(),
                        p.getRazonSocialCliente(),
                        p.getNombreComercialCliente()
                ), Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                        EstadoCuentaVendedorDto::getSaldoPendiente,
                        BigDecimal::add) ))

                .entrySet()
                .stream()

                .map(p -> new EstadoCuentaVendedorDto(p.getKey().getNumeroDocumentoIdentidadCliente(),
                                p.getKey().getRazonSocialCliente(),
                                p.getKey().getNombreComercialCliente(),
                                p.getValue().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
                        )
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }```
````

Comment: The relevance of [tag:rest] and [tag:spring-data] escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

1)if you want to sum them to a single Bigdecimal.
replace the method reference `EstadoCuentaVendedorDto::getSaldoPendiente` to a lambda should work `dto->dto.getSaldoPendienteNoMoroso().add(dto.getSaldoPendienteMoroso())`

2)if you want to do two sum in one groupBy. to define a class holds the two begdecimals and change the reduce

```
class Holder{
Bigdecimal valA;
Bigdecimal valB;
//all args constructor
}

Collectors.reducing(
//create a empty Holder
new Holder(Bigdecimal.ZERO,Bigdecimal.ZERO),
//save data from dto to holder
dto->new Holder(dto.getSaldoPendienteNoMoroso(),dto.getSaldoPendienteMoroso()),
// sum and return 
(a,b)->new Holder(a.getValA().add(b.getValA(),a.getValB().add(b.getValB)
);
```